# Dropzone.js options - cannot get them to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Based on Dropozone.js [FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-submit-additional-data-along-the-file-upload) I have tried to display a message on successful upload.

Code from the `header` looks like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
      init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
          var responseText = "TaDa!";
          file.previewTemplate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(responseText));
        });
      }
    };
)};
</script>
```

And code from the `html` section:

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
```

Drag and drop upload works fine but I'm not getting desired message on `success`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because dropzone initializes before the options are set, to avoid this just place the dropzone options outside the `ready` function.

```
<script>

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            var responseText = "TaDa!";
            file.previewTemplate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(responseText));
            });
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Your other javascript
    )};

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and after trying the solution @wallek876 provided I was still unable to set options for the `#Media_Dropzone` object. finally I've found that Dropzone is unable to find elements with ID's in which contain underscores!! so basically renaming the element from `#Media_Dropzone` to `#MediaDropzone` and of-course implementing the accepted answer here solved my problem.